# Sprite and Body not attached to each other when sprites are scaled Andengine GLES2

Tags: android, andengine

**Sprite** and its **body** dont look to be together when I **scale** my sprites. It works fine when I dont scale them. Please tell me what can I do to fix this.

I am using DebugRenderer to see where is the body and I can see the half of the sprite attached to body. I mean sprite's top left corner is attached to the center of the body.
Not able to post the screenshot

Here's the code

```
final Sprite circle=new Sprite(0, 0, circletexture, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    circle.setScaleX(0.5f);
    circle.setScaleY(0.5f);
    circle.setWidth(circle.getWidthScaled());
    circle.setHeight(circle.getHeightScaled());

    circle.setPosition(CAMERA_WIDTH/2,CAMERA_HEIGHT/2);
    SceneMenu.attachChild(circle);



    final Body circleBody=PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(mPhysicsWorld, circle, BodyType.DynamicBody, fixture);
    mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(circle, circleBody,true,false));
    circleBody.setLinearVelocity(-5f,0);
    SceneMenu.registerUpdateHandler(mPhysicsWorld);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set scal center by using .setScaleCenter() method of the sprite. Experiment and it should work:)